# NestJS - exclude folder under watch mode

Tags: nestjs

I created a public folder within root directory to store user uploaded files. But under `npm run start:dev` mode, every time I upload a file, Nest has detected file change and restarts server. How can I do to avoid this? Thanks.

Dir structure:

```
-project
 -dist
 -src
 -public
 -(other files)
```

Comment: Add the `public` dir to the `tsconfig.json` in the `exclue` array.

Answer (score 24):

Under `tsconfig.json` include the below property immediately after `exclude` property

```
  "include": [ "src"]
```

Comment: This is the correct one, adding only `exclude` is not enough

Comment: Indeed `exclude` didn't work for me as I would expect with `typescript` package `4.0.5`. I upgraded it to `4.7.4` and it became fine with `exclude` now.

Answer (score 8):

Inside `tsconfig.json` file do what I did in the bellow sample:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {

    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "public"   <<-- Add the folder name here to exclude from updates
  ]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

I tried to do the same thing as the other answers but instead, `tsconfig.build.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts","uploads"]
}
```

Added `uploads` folder and it worked for me

Comment: Yup, this works for me too

Comment: Yup there is another tsconfig file for whatever reason!

Answer (score 3):

Insert the following in `tsconfig.json`:

```json
...,
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "public"
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
  "watchOptions": {
    "excludeFiles": ["yourfile"]
  }
```

to your tsconfig.json.

Comment: Thanks, this solution has worked for me. I used the "public" directory as the excluded file and it works correctly unless it is not a file but a dir.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing from above helped so I post my solution. Except "include" and "exclude" in `tsconfig.json` in case of nest, if you have `assets` property defined in `nest-cli.json`, exclude in tsconfig won't work. You can't both watch assets in `nest-cli.json` and ignore them in `tsconfig`.

My *INVALID* `nest-cli.json`:

```json
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "assets": [
    {
      "include": "frontend/dist/**",
      "watchAssets": false,
      "exclude": ["frontend/node_modules", "frontend/src"]
    }
  ]
}
```

so when I tried to use `"exclude": ["frontend"]` in `tsconfig` it didn't work.